# How to close this shut off valve for exterior faucet in the finished basement (1952)

Tags: water, shutoff

We bought this old house (1952) and have a finished basement. Both front and rear outdoor faucets have this shutoff, which we do not know how to operate. What kind of part be needed for shutting off the water? We tried various keys, but nothing fits on it. Markings are made by using the gas shut off key.

[image: Shut off valve both in the front and back of the finished basement for outdoor faucets]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Your picture is too small to see what's going on, but also "help me find a part" questions aren't on-topic here. Please take  our tour to see how better to participate here.

Comment: Do you have hot water heat? That looks more like a bleeder valve than a water shut-off to me....Or, perhaps there's some kind of cover over the valve? A larger picture would help immensely.

Comment: it looks like there was a round object attached to whatever is sticking out of the wall. you can tell by the missing paint. perhaps the knob to turn it broke off?

Comment: why would you post such a bad picture if you are really serious about getting an answer?